# Flutter Splash Screen Stretches Image For A Second On Load

Tags: android, xml, flutter, bitmap, splash-screen

I'm creating a new app using Flutter and wanted to add a custom image on the initial splash screen.

The image appears on the splash screen, however for about half a second it appears stretched which does not look very good.

I've been searching but have struggled to find anyone with the same issue.

Any ideas?

I have tried giving a variable size image using mipmap but produces the same result.

launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:tileMode="disabled"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
    <color name="green">#b7dd05</color>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_app">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutter_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I don't mind the image taking a second the render in, but having it stretched first is not ideal.

[image: First loads in stretched version of image]
[image: What it should like once it has loaded in]

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. If I use the xmls in a normal Android application, the splash screen looks ok, as intended. I don't know how Flutter disrupts the behavior. If you find a solution please answer your question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to provide an image with all the possible sizes (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc) to have the correct size for every screen size and use this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/logo_splash">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This will be my styles:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

finally this will be my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.marianozorrilla">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The result of all these will be the following:

[image: Splash Screen]

In my case, the `logo_splash.png` has a size of **200px-200px** size. If you really want to handle the size in **DP** you'll need to have a minimum **API 23**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/logo_splash"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This one will look like this:

[image: Splash Screen API 23]

Comment: Hi Mariano, thanks for the great reply. I've made the changes you've suggested. However still seem to be having issues with this splash screen. So I started a new flutter default project and added only the image I wanted for the screen. Added the xml you've suggested it works. But then if I try and add a custom color the problem occurs again. ' <color name="primaryColor">#b7dd05</color>' adding this line make the image want to stretch again. Immediately removing it and reloading the problem goes away. This is confusing me as to why. Still new to flutter, but have experience in other languages.

Comment: Did you cleaned your project after making changes in Android? (flutter clean). I'll suggest you to add your colors inside values/colors.xml and then your desire colors to be called later inside your splash or any other place you wish.

Comment: I have moved the <color/> into the colors.xml file and done a fresh "flutter clean" command and saw the build\ get deleted. The stretch is still there. And goes after deleting the <color/> line of code again strangely. Might it be worth sharing the code with you over github?